# GD enabled .. Still have problems . php not compiled --with GD support

Tags: php, gd

5.3.3-7 squeeze15

I have 5.3.3-7 squeeze15 running on a server . I did not compile php using the --with command for GD or anything.

I have installed php5-gd using the standard apt-get install php5-gd. My phpinfo shows GD support

Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/gd.ini

I have checked that gd.ini file it definitely has the gd.so extension Uncommented.

The GD section of the phpinfo shows it all being enabled

GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.2
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.44
WBMP Support

The problem is I am still getting issues with GD , from fatal errors to just not rendering pages where Images are being resized

The php.ini has no ref to gd.so bt that's not needed with the gd.ini file ?

I have read I might needed to recompile php with gd ?

Any ideas would help

Comment: It would help if you mentioned your "issues with GD" and the "fatal errors". Did you try said functions on the same page where the phpinfo() output came from? We can't help with guessing the setup woes anyway.

Comment: I think this belongs on Server Fault (http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the issue was that php was not compiled with the GD option , so this meant that a call to imageantialias() was failing.

Removing that line and thus that functionality removed the error see below what the php manual says ,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php

> ```
> Note: This function is only available if PHP is compiled with the bundled version of the GD library.
> ```

Granted that dos not solve the issue but it is a way around it in case someone else has the same issue.